# Conditional async code pattern

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, conditional-statements

Given the following code pattern:

```
if (doAsyncCall) {
    asyncCall().then(after);
} else {
    after();
}
```

Is there a better way to handle the code that should always run, but if the async code is run, should wait for it to finish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an empty promise:

```
const step1 = doAsyncCall ? asyncCall() : Promise.resolve();
step1.then(after);
```

Answer (score 0):

You might consider something like this:

```
let promise = Promise.resolve();

if (doAsyncCall) {
    promise = asyncCall();
}

promise.then(after);
```

That looks ugly like that, but consider that you could use this pattern where you pass a promise into a function rather than a flag to indicate if a call should be made, or you could factor it out into another function that either returns the async call promise or an already resolve promise.

By only refering to `after` once, the code is more DRY.